# Struts2 isn't mapping correctly textfield from JSP to Action Class

Tags: jsp, struts2, javabeans, textfield

I have a problem with a Struts2 2.3.28 J2EE webapp deployed and running into Apache Tomcat 8. I have a JSP file in which a form is present and it contains a textfield with some name:

classificazioni.jsp:

```
<s:form action="editCategorie" >
<s:textfield label="Nome" name="namedCat" value="ciao"/>
<!--
    <s:textfield label="Nome" name="catBean.namedCat" value="ciao"/>
-->

...
```

I want to access this textfield value into the respective ActionClass, in which I provided the property's declaration and getter and setter:

EditCategorie.java:

```
private String namedCat;

public String getNamedCat() {
    return namedCat;
}

public void setNamedCat(String namedCat) {
    this.namedCat = namedCat;
}

/*
private CatBean catBean;


public CatBean getCatBean() {
    return catBean;
}

public void setCatBean(CatBean catBean) {
    this.catBean = catBean;
}
*/

public String execute()
{
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String display()
{
    System.out.println(getNamedCat());
    // System.out.println(getCatBean().getNamedCat());
    return NONE;    
}
```

I know that this way the webapp should work correctly and print the namedCat textfield value when the display method is invoked. Here is my struts.xml interesting parts:

```
<interceptors>
    <interceptor-stack name="mystack">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
    </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>

<action name="editCategorie" class="it.unisalento.se.actions.EditCategorie">
        <interceptor-ref name="mystack"/>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">classificazioni</result>
    </action>

    <action name="showCategorie" class="it.unisalento.se.actions.EditCategorie" method="display">
        <interceptor-ref name="mystack"/>
        <result name="none" type="tiles">classificazioni</result>
    </action>
```

I've just tried two different approaches, as you've noticed reading the code, but when I try to print the namedCat into EditCategorie's display method the console shows 'null', whilst with the Bean approach, despite I know Struts2 should automatically instantiate the bean class by itself with the correct filled attributes, this doesn't happen and obviously when I try to access to the namedCat property of the catBean instance I get a NullPointerException.

Eventually this is also the CatBean.java class:

```
public CatBean()
{

}

private String namedCat;

public String getNamedCat() {
    return namedCat;
}

public void setNamedCat(String namedCat) {
    this.namedCat = namedCat;
}
```

I have read many times here that the main Struts2 advantage is to avoid the use of direct Servlet's logic, and also I have read here that this two approaches should work. I know I could use also a ModelDriven approach (this works perfectly in other actions), but I have to deal with parametric textfields so it is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts 2 actions are instantiated per-request.

There is no data in the newly-instantiated action, hence nothing to display, when you hit the `showCategorie` URL. If you want to persist the value you'd need to keep it somewhere, e.g., database, session, application, etc.